# Letting CSS interact with HTML through PHP

Tags: php, css, html

The following is my PHP code:

```
$heads = array();
$heads[0] = "<p class='ourmoto'>Your camera solutions...</p>";
$heads[1] = "<a href='index.html'><img id='rentals' src='images/rentalsnew2.jpg' alt='GroupLogo' /></a>";
$heads[2] = "<p class='ourmoto'>...Your camera solutions</p>";

for ($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){
  echo"<p>$heads[$i]</p>";  
}
```

CSS:

```
.ourmoto {
    font-style:oblique;
    font-size:30px;
    display:inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

From my knowledge, echo should print whatever comes after it in a quote as a string, even if its HTML tags. It manages to print the HTML but CSS won't apply on it. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: This won't be the cause of the symptoms you describe, but HTML forbids `<p>` elements from containing other `<p>` elements.

Comment: your echo does not have a p class=.., just paragraph. So it will not use the css style defined.

Comment: @DevionNL — The classes are in the data in the array!

Comment: The code works fine when I test it. I can't reproduce the problem. http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/47390247/ — The problem most likely has to do with how you are associating the CSS with the HTML.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the versions of php or anything?

Comment: Your question tells us you haven't (re)searched much before asking. Please read [ask] for details. If you did research, let us know about it or people will tend to think you haven't done it and therefore will be less willing to help.

Answer (score -3):

Iterate through each heads, echo paragraph with class:

```
foreach ($heads as $head)
  echo "<p class='ourmoto'>{$head}</p>";  
}
```